# regex for nested tags in perl

Tags: regex, perl, tags, nested

I got this solution but this is not working for nested tags like multiple span tag. Can you help me out?

```
message =~ s#
&lt;
(?<tag>span|em|ul|ol)   
&gt;
(.*?)
&lt;
/
\k<tag>   
&gt;
#
<$+{tag}>  
$2    
</$+{tag}>
#xg;
```

Comment: Use real html parser. and read: http://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/632407

Answer (score 0):

Untested:

```
use Web::Query qw();
Web::Query
    ->new_from_html($message)
    ->find('span,em,ul,ol')
    ->replace_with(sub { $_->html })
    ->as_html;
```